# Giving input to /set \package at runtime

Tags: batch-file

In a batch file, I have replaced the hard coded dB name with a parameter that I am reading from a file. When I run the batch file from local, I can see the dB name getting properly replaced. However, when I am trying to run the same script on WLM, the job is getting aborted without triggering the underlying package itself.

Code for reading from file:

```
for /f "delims== tokens=2" %%G in (file_name.txt) do set %%dB_name=%%H
```

I am using `DTEXEC` in the batch file and the parameter is being passed to the `/set \"package[variable]";dB_name`

Answer (score 0):

Using `file_name.txt` of:

```
ABC=DEF
GHI=JKI
```

And your batch line, I find the following variable getting set:

```
%dB_name=%H
```

I suspect that's not what you actually want.  Normally you don't want the percent sign *in* your variable name.

Also, while you specify token #2, that is the only token you specify, so I suspect your target should be `%%G` instead of `%%H`.

Perhaps something like this would work better:

```
for /f "delims== tokens=2" %%G in (file_name.txt) do set dB_name=%%G
```

Also, I can no longer remember why but I'm a big fan of putting `delims` last:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%G in (file_name.txt) do set dB_name=%%G
```

In any regard, the result I get when I do this is, using the same input file, is:

```
dB_name=JKI
```

Which looks a whole lot more like what you're trying accomplish.